# PageController ignores Listener

Tags: flutter, dart, mouseevent, listener, flutter-pageview

I'm trying  to change page in a [PageView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/PageView-class.html) when the mouse scrolls,

I'm using a [Listener](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Listener-class.html) following this [article](https://medium.com/@crizantlai/flutter-handling-mouse-events-241108731537),

in my implementation (https://dartpad.dartlang.org/c2b24881927981575ff81367121f4e5f)

using the fabs it behave as expected:

- move to the new page
- print the new page number
- `then` prints either `next` or `previous` page

but the callback in the `Listener` behave weirdly :

- print the message from the callback
- does NOT move to a new page
- but `then` prints either `next` or `previous` page

I'm not sure what is the cause of this behavior, any idea?
Thank you

Comment: can you provide some code?

Comment: @PedroR. the dartpad was in the "implementation" link, I edited the post to make it more visible

Comment: this is because `PageView` takes input from the mouse scroller without the need of listener.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set physics property of `PageView`

```
physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()
```

so the `PageView` ignores the pointer, use the feedback picked up by `Listener` move to pages

Comment: following your suggestion I changed the implementation as follow
https://dartpad.dartlang.org/c3476573514298b9885b78a0275c744c
and works as intended
thank you @Yadu